# Scope of an anonymous function as an argument

Tags: javascript, html, css, this, anonymous-function

I'm working on a very simple application. When the user hovers over any list item (`li`), then the text color changes to green, and when the mouse is out it goes back black.

Why can't we use `lis[i]` in the following piece of code inside the anonymous function instead of `this` keyword?

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var i = 0;
for(; i < lis.length; i++){

    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){

    this.style.color = 'green';

    });
    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){

    this.style.color ="black";  
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

When the callback function will be executed, the `i` variable will have the value of `lis.length` because of the loop, leading to the value of `lis[i]` to be `undefined`.

What you could do is use the `forEach` function instead.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
lis.forEach(function (li) {
  li.addEventListener('mouseover', function (){
    li.style.color = 'green';
  });
  li.addEventListener('mouseout', function (){
    li.style.color ="black";  
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First LI</li>
  <li>Second LI</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, ```i``` will still be defined, but stuck on the last value of the for loop (in this case lis.length, making ```lis[i]``` undefined). This is due to Javascript closures. See @Duncan's answer.

Comment: @MichaelYang thanks for pointing it out, I was more focus on the solution than the root of the problem

Comment: Of course — your solution is very good! I just wanted to point that out :-)

Answer (score 2):

At the time the function is called the loop will have completed. There is only one `i` variable and the function always sees its current value. So if you use `i` from inside the function you will see it with the value `lis.length`.

There are ways around it. If you can use ES2015 (possibly through a transpiler), then you can write:

```
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for(let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){

    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => lis[i].style.color = 'green');
    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseout', () => lis[i].style.color ="black");
};
```

and now you have a different `i` for each time round the loop.

Or in older code you can push the loop body out to another function and pass `i` in as a parameter. That has the same effect of binding a different variable for each event:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

var _loop = function _loop(i) {

    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        return lis[i].style.color = 'green';
    });
    lis[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        return lis[i].style.color = "black";
    });
};

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    _loop(i);
}
```

(which is the code automatically produced by babel from the ES2015 example I gave above)

Answer (score -1):

you can use "e.srcElement" to get current target like this

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li');

for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e){
    e.srcElement.style.color = 'green';
  })
  lis[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
    e.srcElement.style.color = 'black';
  })
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First LI</li>
  <li>Second LI</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They can, but that has nothing to do with the question they asked